# Who owes who money algorithm in excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I have a group of people who have different expenses during a period. Everybody has a balance after this period. It looks like this in excel:

Person A: 6 
Person B: 10 
Person C: -7,5 
Person D: -8,5

After this period a settlement will take place. I currently do this by manually. This results in:

Person C pays 6 to person A. 
Person C pays 1,5 to person B. 
Person D pays 8,5 to person B.

Person A gets 6 from person C. 
Person B gets 1,5 form person C. 
Peron B gets 8,5 from person D.

(There are multiple solutions possible when more persons are involved.)

The problem is that I have to apply this procedure for a big group of people. So my question is: 'How to apply this 'who owes who'-procedure by using an excel spreadsheet algorithm or macro?'.

Comment: The question makes no sense; how do you derive that person C pays person A and B, and person D only pays B?

Comment: nice question. i know you can do it with a macro, but i do not have macros for excel. will a open office or html (javascript) solution work for you?

Comment: Yes that could probably work for me, but I prefer to have it solved in excel. That would be the best in my situation.

Comment: @maarten-steinfort see new answer

Comment: @maarten-steinfort thanks for the accept now how about a up vote too? spent 3 hours on this !

Comment: I'll give you one - I can never work this stuff out when in a restaurant.  Would be quite a handy smartphone app...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a excel version too but its in Open office. can you download that? The following macro might work on its own. If it does not should be something small. it works fine in OOO and is saved as a Excel 97/2000 workbook document.

```
'this might not be needed in Microsoft Excel, comment it out
Option VBASupport 1 'OWES

Option Explicit
'Cells(row, col), 
Private Sub cmd1_Click()
'data is same sheet, from row 4, column 4
'row 4 has names in columns, so 4,4 has name 1, 4,5 has name 2
'row 5 has amounts spent like 6, -10
'output is in columns 3 and 5

dim i 
dim j,s as String, sum1
s=""

'get number of cells used in row 4 and check if corresponding row 6 column has a number value too
i = 4
sum1=0
do while(cells(4,i).Value <> "" and i < 500) 

    j = CDbl(cells(5,i).Value)
    sum1 = sum1 + j
    if j <> cells(5,i).Value then
        MsgBox "Col " & i & " not a number?"
        End
    end if
    i=i+1
loop
if i > 499 then
    Msgbox "too many cols"
    End
end if

If sum1 > 0.3 or sum1 < -0.3   then
    Msgbox "Sum is not near 0 :" & sum1
    End
End if


Dim colCnt as Integer
colCnt = i - 4
cells (7,1).Value = "Col count = " & colCnt
Dim spent(colCnt) as Double
Dim owes1(colCnt ) as String
Dim owes2(colCnt ) as String


for i= 4 to colCnt + 3
    spent(i - 3) = CDbl(cells(5,i).Value)
Next

Dim cnt,lastNeg, abs1,maxPay  ' safety var for never ending loops, only if data bad like many cols and more than .1 diffs
lastNeg = 4
dim lastPay1
lastPay1 = 10
dim ii,jj,c1,c2,toPay
toPay = 0
On Local Error Goto errh
for i= 4 to colCnt + 3
    cnt = 0
    ii = i - 3
    c1 =  spent(ii)
    'Cells(6,i) = "ok "
    if spent(ii) > 0.1 and cnt < colCnt Then '//has to take
        cnt = cnt + 1
        for j = lastNeg  to colCnt + 3 ' ; j < people.length && spent(ii) > 0.1; j++)
            jj = j - 3
            's = s & Me.Cells(ii,j) & " " 
            if spent(ii) > 0.1 then
                if spent(jj) < -0.1 Then ' //has to give and has balance to give
                    c1 =  spent(ii)
                    c2 =  spent(jj)
                    lastNeg = j
                    abs1 = spent(jj) * -1'//can use absolute fn
                    maxPay = abs1
                    if(maxPay > spent(ii)) Then
                        toPay =  spent(ii)'
                    else 
                        toPay = abs1
                    End if
                    spent(ii) = spent(ii) - toPay
                    spent(jj) = spent(jj) + toPay
                    Cells(lastPay1, 3).Value = Cells(4 , j) & " pays " & toPay & " to " & Cells(4 , i )
                    Cells(lastPay1, 5).Value  = Cells(4 , i) & " gets  " & toPay & " from " & Cells(4 , j)
                    lastPay1 = lastPay1 + 1
                End if

            End if
        Next
    End if
Next
Msgbox "Done"
err.Clear
if err.Number <> 0 Then
  errH:
  dim yy
  yy = msgBox("err " & err.Number & " " & err.Description & " Continue", 2)
  if yy = vbYes Then
     Resume Next
  End IF
End IF
End Sub
```

Book at http://sel2in.com/prjs/vba/profile (owes)

Can see http://www.excel-vba.com/ , http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/training/get-in-the-loop-with-excel-macros-RZ001150634.aspx the help in excel was useful too (f1 inside macro editor, can select a keyword or type and get context sensitive help by pressing f1)

Answer (score 1):

How important is the pairing of who owes what to who?  The reason I ask - it's simple to figure out the total cost per person and then determine who owes money and who needs a refund.  If one person can be the "banker", he can collect all the money due and disburse all the refunds.

Much simpler question, if you have somebody willing to be the banker.

Trying to pair everything up will quite possibly not result in an exact answer, or may require one or more people making payments to more than one person - as well as one or more people trying to collect from more than one other person.

Answer (score 0):

See http://sel2in.com/pages/prog/html/owes.html

Javascript fn

```
<form>

Paste tab seperated list of people on first line, Second line has blanace - positive means they spent more than others, negative means other spent on them (they owe)
<br>
<textarea id=t1 rows=3 cols=70></textarea>

</form>

<button onclick=calcOwes() >Calc owes</button>

<br>
<b>Result:</b>
<div id=result>Will appear here if data is good</div>
<br>
<b>Parsed data for debug:</b>
<div id=data1>Will appear here if data is good</div>

<br>
<hr>
<script>
function calcOwes(){
/**
2013    Tushar Kapila
If Person A: 6
Person B: 10
Person C: -7,5
Person D: -8,5

Then Person C pays 6 to person A.
Person C pays 1,5 to person B.
Person D pays 8,5 to person B.
*/
s = document.getElementById("t1").value

    var line = s.split("\n")
    //v = confirm("Your Data looks okay?:\n" + s)
    //if(!v){ return;}
    if(s.length < 2 || s.indexOf("\n") < 0){
        alert("No line sep ")
        return
    }
    people = line[0].split("\t")
    spent = line[1].split("\t")
    spent2 = line[1].split("\t")
    if(spent.length < 2){
        alert("Bad data, no spent data " + spent.length + "; 0 " + spent[0] + "; 1 " +  + spent[1])
        return
    }
    if(people.length != spent.length){
        alert("People and amounts do not tally. make sure no tabs inside names, spaces are okay")
        return
    }

    sum  = 0;
    data1o = document.getElementById("data1")
    data1o.innerHTML = "";
    for(i = 0;i < people.length; i++){
        spent[i] = spent[i].trim()
        spent[i] = parseFloat(spent[i])
        sum += spent[i]
        s = (1 + i) + " \"" + people[i] + "\" :" + spent[i] + ";<br>"
        data1o.innerHTML += s;
    }
    if(sum > 0.2 || sum < -0.2){
        v = confirm("Sum (" + sum + ")is not zero continue?")
        if(!v){return;}
    }
    lastNeg = 0;
    payDetails = new Array();
    getDetails = new Array();
    lastPay = 0;

    for(i = 0;i < people.length; i++){
        cnt = 0;
        if(spent[i] > 0.1 && cnt < people.length){//has to take
            cnt++
            for(j = lastNeg; j < people.length && spent[i] > 0.1; j++){
                if(spent[j] < -0.1){//has to give and has balance to give
                    lastNeg = j;
                    abs1 = spent[j] * -1;//can use absolute fn
                    maxPay = abs1
                    if(maxPay > spent[i]){
                        toPay =  spent[i];
                    }else{
                        toPay = abs1
                    }
                    spent[i] -= toPay
                    spent[j] += toPay
                    payDetails[lastPay] = people[j] + " pays " + toPay + " to " + people[i]
                    getDetails[lastPay] = people[i] + " gets  " + toPay + " from " + people[j]
                    lastPay++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    s = ""
    s2 = ""
    for(i = 0;i < lastPay; i++){
        s = s + payDetails[i] + "<br>"
        s2 = s2 + getDetails[i] + "<br>"
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = s + "<br>" + s2
}

</script>
 <br>Sample input 1 (tabs there?)
 <br><pre>
 a  b   c   d
 6  10  -7.5    -8.5
 </pre>

 <br>Sample input 2
 <pre>
 Anna Dan   Bobby Scareface Colly   Doc Egg face
 -6 10  -7.3    -8.33   11.67
 </pre>
```

Comment: tabs did not make it in samples. but should work if you copy from excel cells. excel uses tabs as cell seperator. might have to split on \n\r if excel adds that -> if some one has excel please test

Comment: I tested with decimal separator period as in 1.5

Comment: Works great! Copied it from excel to the browser. But the thing is still that I am wondering how to perform this same action within excel.

Comment: you can post this to excel pretty easily. are you a programmer your self? if so google "vba Excel" i can give you some links of excel documents with macros i made earlier. it is pretty easy to refer to cells in sheets and do math and other functions on them, and write to other cells

Comment: Never worked with vba but should succeed to that! Some links would be great.